# How to change columns value to Dataframe value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change columns to dataframe "code" value in Pandas and delete index values.
Please advice below code,,,

```
total_col_code = standard_df['code'].values
total_col_imp = standard_df['imp'].values
total_col_score = standard_df['score'].values
total_col_data = {'code':total_col_code, 'imp': total_col_imp, 'score': total_col_score}
df_total_col_data= pd.DataFrame(total_col_data).T

# Now I get it like this 
    0   1   2   3   4   5
   code U-1 U-2 U-3 U-4 U-5
   imp  3   4   5   6   7
   score3   3   3   3   2

# and I want to get it like this

 code   U-1 U-2 U-3 U-4 U-5
 imp     3   4   5   6   7
 score   3   3   3   3   2
 # columns : code values!
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# maybe you can use:
df_total_col_data.columns = df.iloc[0] # the values of 'code' row
# and delete 'code' row
df_total_col_data = df_total_col_data.iloc[1:]
```